# Stored procedure fails because CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL is incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that generates XML. It works great in DEV, but in other environments it fails with the following exception message.

This is a new error to me. I am reading-up various blogs on the issue, but I'm unsure I fully understand it yet. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

The exception looks like this:

[image]

This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_OutboundEventMessage_CREATE]
    (@EventName NVARCHAR(200),
     @Force bit = 0,
     @TopicFilter NVARCHAR(100),
     @EventContexts XML,
     @MessageBody XML OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ----------------------
    -- DETECT FORAMATTING: ContextKey
    ----------------------
    IF (SELECT @EventContexts.exist('(//Contexts)')) = 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Contexts XML = '<Contexts>' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), @EventContexts) + '</Contexts>';
        SET @EventContexts = @Contexts;
    END

    ----------------------
    -- CREATE FORAMATTING: DataSource
    ----------------------
    DECLARE @EmptyGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = (SELECT CAST(0x0 AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER));
    DECLARE @DataSource XML = (SELECT (SELECT SERVERPROPERTY(N'MachineName')) AS '@machineName', (SELECT Name FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID()) FOR XML PATH('DataSource'))
    DECLARE @Topic XML = (SELECT @TopicFilter AS Filter FOR XML PATH('Topic'))

    ----------------------
    -- GENERATE: MessageBody
    --
    -- ATTRIBUTES: Are added through as simle columns (see below)
    ----------------------
    SET @MessageBody =  (SELECT
                        @EmptyGuid AS '@auditId',
                        CASE  @Force WHEN 0 THEN 'false' ELSE 'true' END AS '@force',
                        GETUTCDATE() AS '@CreatedOn',
                        @DataSource,
                        @Topic,
                        Name = @EventName,
                        @EventContexts 
                    FOR XML PATH('Event'))
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure the blogs you have read explain what that setting does and [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx) explains further.

To resolve your problem you can just add the following at the top of your stored procedure:

```
SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON
```

Comment: It turns out that the various environment are configured differently...so yes...I had to add this.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Indexed Views require that certain SET conditions be in place (they are the recommended settings anyway). The setting that a stored procedure is supposed to execute under are recorded when it is created.  If these two do not match and you are using an indexed view in the procedure then you get this error.

To fix this, drop the procedure, turn the setting on in your session, and then recreate the procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Check the ANSI PADDING setting
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187403.aspx

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on this?

Comment: The error message is quite clearly complaining about `CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` not `ANSI_PADDING`